# Is this a case of inappropriate usage of generic?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out purpose of one interesting usage of generic:

let's consider this class as an example:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public personName: string) { }

    setName(name: string) {
        this.personName = name
    }
}
```

and this decorator:

```
export function logger<T extends any[]>(message: string | ((...msgArgs: T) => string)) {
    return (_target: object, _propertyKey: string, propDesc: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        const classMethod = propDesc.value;
        propDesc.value = function (...args: T) {
            const logMsg: string = typeof message === 'function' ? message.apply(this, args) : message;
            console.log(logMsg)
            const result = classMethod.call(this, ...args);

            return result;
        };

        return propDesc;
    };
}
```

We can use it like this:

```
@logger("Setting name")
setName(name: string) {
        this.personName = name
    }
```

or

```
@logger((nameParam)=> `Setting name ${nameParam}`)
setName(name: string) {
        this.personName = name
    }
```

Works as intended. However I don't understand why this should be a generic:

```
logger<T extends any[]>
```

Yes, it gives us an ability to use `T` instead of `any[]` in multiple places.
But it looks like this is just a tricky workaround and abusing generic syntax. Basically this generic has nothing to do with generics...
And even worst thing is that decorator `propDesc.value = function` and an argument function `| ((...msgArgs: T) => string)` are sharing same type even though they have nothing in common.

I'm still feeling I might be wrong in the statement above.
So I would like to know is there any reasons for using generic at this particular case in favor of `any[]` or `type anyArg = any[]`

p.s. I have a strong feeling that implementation was inspired by [this article](https://mattburgess.medium.com/javascript-shinies-decorators-4fa005638022)

Comment: What determines whether it is appropriate or inappropriate, other than opinion?

Answer (score 1):

In this case `T` is used just for typing `rest` operator.

And, you are right, there is no sence to use `T extends any[]`, since we can just use in next way:

```js
export function logger<T,>(message: string | ((...msgArgs: T[]) => string)) {
    return (_target: object, _propertyKey: string, propDesc: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        const classMethod = propDesc.value;
        propDesc.value = function (...args: T[]) {
            const logMsg: string = typeof message === 'function' ? message.apply(this, args) : message;
            console.log(logMsg)
            const result = classMethod.call(this, ...args);

            return result;
        };

        return propDesc;
    };
}
```

Consider next example:

```js
export function logger<T,>(message: string | ((...msgArgs: T[]) => string)) {

}

logger((...args: string[]) => 'bar')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAimA8AcHsCcBcAEAzArgOwMbwJbXYgDbQDmJosAPACoA0AfABQC2oAzmwIbkBcib8WDnQlEAH0SNGAOlnM2JAIKwSbPtQDaAXQCUiALz1%20g4SR16A3iAC%20IYmQpTZ0zirXGhI7XsOIA5ABGrn46QA)

Please hover your mouse on `logger((...args: string[]) => 'bar')`

You should see, that `T` generic was infered to string :

```js
function logger<string>(message: string | ((...msgArgs: string[]) => string)): void
```

Wait, what if I ger rid of this generic?

```js
export function logger(message: string | ((...msgArgs: unknown[]) => string)) {

}


logger((...args:number[])=>'foo') // error
```

I'm no more able to type `args` array.

Comment: Wait... Is comma after `T` is doing that trick (`T,`)?

Comment: Partialy -- yes

Comment: You should use comma trick because TS treats it as JSX.